# Alternate OAuth2 sign in for a PyQt5 application

Tags: python, pyqt5, google-oauth

I have a PyQt5 application with a Google sign-in which is implemented using [oauth2client](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client). And the sign in page is shown in an embedded browser using `QWebEngineView`. But with [Google blocking sign in workflows using embedded browsers from Jan 4, 2021](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html), there will be a change required in my application to open system browser instead and then receive the authorization response from that. For that, I am using [google-auth-oauthlib](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib), which is also used in the [Google Python Quickstart Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

I have created a small POC that just implements this workflow, but I am facing a couple of issues:

1. The sign in page is opened in a new browser window or a tab. But this might not be a great UX as the user has to close the browser after signing in and then get back to the application. Opening a popup browser seems like a better UX here. I checked the source code of `run_local_server` method that is responsible for opening the browser, and they seem to use the `webbrowser` module, which unfortunately does not have a way of opening a popup.
2. If the user closes the browser opened using `run_local_server` method without signing in, the application that is calling it just freezes and needs to be force quit. I did not notice any console errors as well. Is there even a way to handle this with the library that I am using?

Here is the minimum working example:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QStandardPaths
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

class GoogleSignIn(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            "credentials.json", # This file should be placed in the correct folder
            scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "openid",
                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"])

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.sign_in_btn = QPushButton('Sign In', self)
        self.sign_in_btn.move(135, 135)
        self.sign_in_btn.setFixedSize(100, 40)
        self.sign_in_btn.clicked.connect(self.open_google_sign_in)

        self.setFixedSize(350, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Google Sign in Test')
        self.show()

    def open_google_sign_in(self):
        self.flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        session = self.flow.authorized_session()

        profile_info = session.get('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me').json()
        print(profile_info)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GoogleSignIn()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QWebEngineView can be used as a browser for authentication but you must set a valid user-agent. On the other hand, google-auth-oauthlib requests are blocking so they must be executed in a different thread and notify the result through signals:

```py
import functools
import logging
import os
import pickle
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "openid",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
]
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class Reply(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, func, args=(), kwargs=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._results = None
        self._is_finished = False
        self._error_str = ""
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(func, args, kwargs), daemon=True
        ).start()

    @property
    def results(self):
        return self._results

    @property
    def error_str(self):
        return self._error_str

    def is_finished(self):
        return self._is_finished

    def has_error(self):
        return bool(self._error_str)

    def _execute(self, func, args, kwargs):
        if kwargs is None:
            kwargs = {}
        try:
            self._results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            self._error_str = str(e)
        self._is_finished = True
        self.finished.emit()


def convert_to_reply(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        reply = Reply(func, args, kwargs)
        return reply

    return wrapper


class Backend(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QUrl)
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._service = None

    @property
    def service(self):
        if self._service is None:
            reply = self._update_credentials()
            loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
            reply.finished.connect(loop.quit)
            loop.exec_()
            if not reply.has_error():
                self._service = reply.results
            else:
                logging.debug(reply.error_str)
        return self._service

    @convert_to_reply
    def _update_credentials(self):
        creds = None
        if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
            with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
                creds = pickle.load(token)
        if not creds or not creds.valid:
            if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
            else:
                flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    "credentials.json", SCOPES
                )
                host = "localhost"
                port = 8080
                state = "default"
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(
                    0, functools.partial(self.get_url, flow, host, port, state)
                )
                creds = flow.run_local_server(
                    host=host, port=port, open_browser=False, state=state
                )
                self.finished.emit()
            with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
                pickle.dump(creds, token)
        return build("oauth2", "v2", credentials=creds)

    def get_url(self, flow, host, port, state):
        flow.redirect_uri = "http://{}:{}/".format(host, port)
        redirect_uri, _ = flow.authorization_url(state=state)
        self.started.emit(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(redirect_uri))

    @convert_to_reply
    def get_user_info(self):
        return self.service.userinfo().get().execute()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.backend = Backend()

        self.webengineview = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        self.webengineview.page().profile().setHttpUserAgent(
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0"
        )
        self.webengineview.hide()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Sign in")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.webengineview)

        button.clicked.connect(self.sign_in)
        self.backend.started.connect(self.handle_url_changed)
        self.backend.finished.connect(self.webengineview.hide)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def sign_in(self):
        reply = self.backend.get_user_info()
        wrapper = functools.partial(self.handle_finished_user_info, reply)
        reply.finished.connect(wrapper)

    def handle_finished_user_info(self, reply):
        if reply.has_error():
            logging.debug(reply.error_str)
        else:
            profile_info = reply.results
            print(profile_info)

    def handle_url_changed(self, url):
        self.webengineview.load(url)
        self.webengineview.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Running google-auth-oauthlib requests from a different thread solves the issue. But regarding the setting of user agent using `QWebEngineView`, this is what is mentioned in the blog post:


_The browser must identify itself clearly in the User-Agent. The browser must not try to impersonate another browser like Chrome or Firefox._

Aren't we impersonating Firefox here?

Comment: @Shreehari Google oauth2 has a list of user-agents that it considers valid created without any standards based, and in this case it established one that is in that list. IMO that list seems silly to me since as you realize I have gone through it without problems that in theory it should give you an improvement in security but in practice it is useless.

Comment: @Shreehari The user-agent aims to identify the browser so that the developers of the pages can adapt their technology to that particular browser since certain APIs are only available in certain browsers and not in others.

Comment: @Shreehari Note: I got the idea from the qutebrowser issue that implements this logic for certain pages. https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/5182

Comment: Understood. I will go ahead and the valid user agent.