# Transferring Google OAuth2 data from the application to the website

Tags: python, pyqt5, google-oauth, pyside6, pyqt6

I created an app and it also has a web browser inside. So If I log in using the my app, I don't want to login again for my website (that opened in my app).

[Alternate OAuth2 sign in for a PyQt5 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121625/alternate-oauth2-sign-in-for-a-pyqt5-application)

there is a good example and it works just fine but I was wondering that can I send/transfer those response information to the endpoint of my website (the website is opened in my pyside6 app) so that it can log in to my website as well? I have already a google authentication system on my website. Not sure but I think google use same or similar authentication system for the desktop and website applications.

is there a way to do this?